# icloud sync withoud internet

Tags: ios, swift

i will upgrade my app with the feature icloud sync.

short example:

in my app is a tablew view, where you can save new entries.
this entries will be save in core data.

i would like to realize this:

check if iCloud is activ ?

-> yes -> entries will be save in iCloud / request from there

-> no -> entries will be save in core data / request from there

the topic "icloud" is new for me - i have got open questions.
if icloud is activ, i check before an entry will be save if an internet connection is available.

- what should i do if not connection is available? where should i save this entry?
- when and how should i later save this entry into icloud?

My Entries should be available without internet connection, too.

- how should i show this entries, if i cant request them form icloud?

My app use ios 9 swift 2

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the core data storage as primary and use iCloud only for syncing changes. This will allow you great offline user experience. I suppose the user can have multiple devices (e.g. phone and an iPad) and you want to be able to sync between all their devices, which can be achieved with CloudKit SDK. Check out the [intro to CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-208/) and [Advanced CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-231/) videos from WWDC 2014.

Comment: yes this will be the way i would like to realize that. but what is the best way to compare the data of core data and icloud?

Comment: CloudKit has an API for that and it is explained in the second video I linked.